# PHP mail form - email header

Tags: php, forms, email, header

I am using a PHP mail form on my site. I receive mail just fine but the headers I am getting are in the form `a7849972@srv29.000webhost.com`, and the same for reply address. How can I change my code to get the person's name in header? I am using the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $to = 'chander_info@yahoo.com' ;     //put your email address on which you want to      receive the information
   $subject = 'Message - Contact Form Coast Med Spa';   //set the subject of email.
   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["FirstName"]."\r\n"; 
   $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
   $message = "<table>
           <tr><td>Title</td><td>".$_POST['Title']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>First Name</td><td>".$_POST['FirstName']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Last Name</td><td>".$_POST['LastName']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>E-Mail</td><td>".$_POST['Email']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Phone Number</td><td>".$_POST['HomePhone']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Comments</td><td>".$_POST['CAT_Custom_869']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Contact Method</td><td>".$_POST['CAT_Custom_868']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Subscribe to: eNewsletter</td>     <td>".$_POST['CampaignList_41798']."</td></tr>
           </table>" ;
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $mailheader);
   header('Location: http://coastlasercenter.com/html/message-contact.html');
echo "Your message has been received";
}
?>
```

Comment: You better use a mailer class like `PHPmailer`. The build-in `mail()` function doesn't fit today's email standards and is hard to modify for such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you separating headers into two different variables?
You're passing the `From` and `Reply-to` headers as additional parameters to the `mail()` function. Check PHP's [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $to = 'chander_info@yahoo.com' ;     //put your email address on which you want to      receive the information
   $subject = 'Message - Contact Form Coast Med Spa';   //set the subject of email.
   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "From: ".$_POST['FirstName']." ".$_POST['LastName']." <".$_POST['Email'].">\r\n"; 
   $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
   $message = "<table>
           <tr><td>Title</td><td>".$_POST['Title']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>First Name</td><td>".$_POST['FirstName']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Last Name</td><td>".$_POST['LastName']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>E-Mail</td><td>".$_POST['Email']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Phone Number</td><td>".$_POST['HomePhone']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Comments</td><td>".$_POST['CAT_Custom_869']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Contact Method</td><td>".$_POST['CAT_Custom_868']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Subscribe to: eNewsletter</td>     <td>".$_POST['CampaignList_41798']."</td></tr>
           </table>" ;
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   header('Location: http://coastlasercenter.com/html/message-contact.html');
echo "Your message has been received";
}
?>
```

BTW, you should consider validating the data you're getting in $_POST before concatenating it to your email headers since it can lead to [email injection attacks](http://phpsense.com/2006/php-email-injection-attacks/).

Comment: Another thing, looking at the rest of your code: if you're redirecting the client to another page, he won't be able to see what you echo after sending the Location headers. You should display your message on message-contact.html

Comment: yes echo i have forget to remove it was there for testing only...the validation i have in contact-us.html file

Comment: Did the changes I suggested on your script help you?

Comment: Look at the headers of the email you're receiving, there might be something there that helps you to understand what's happening. There's also the chance that 000webhost is rewriting your email headers. If this is the case, there's not much you can do from your script. You should contact the server administrators for that.

Comment: In fact 000webhost i am using for testing only the main site coastmedspa.com and on their webmail also I am having the same issue, though there sender is chander@rs19.abstractdns.com in the header

Comment: What about the headers of the email you're receiving?

Comment: headers i am receiving the reply address is coming good but only the sender I am receiving is apples@rs19.abstractdns.com, Please see the image http://tutorial.netne.net/header-issue.JPG

Comment: Try adding the email address on the From: headers as was suggested in another answer: `$headers .= "From: ".$_POST["FirstName"]." <".$_POST['Email'].">";`. I'm editing my answer to add this, because it would probably not work properly without the email address on that header.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this format in your code:

```
$headers .= "From: ".$userName." <".$userEmailAddress.">";
```

By the way it's better to use **utf-8** instead of **iso-8859-1** for your charset.

Comment: What values I have to put in .$userName and .$userEmailAddress.

Comment: $userName must be `$_POST["FirstName"]` and $userEmailAddress must be `$_POST["email"]`

Comment: HURRAY! it worked thanks a lot to both Md. Saberi and  Andrés Gattinoni . Even I added last name it too `$headers .= "From: ".$_POST['FirstName']." ".$_POST['LastName']." <".$_POST['Email'].">";`